ios linphone chat notification integration
I have integrated the voip call notification successfully in ios app for linphone ,but for chat i am not getting notification but its not loading the chat in the conversation i mean
            let message = lc!.getNewMessageFromCallid(callId: callId)

This line of code always returning nil for me
Can any one please help me for fix this one
either tell me the step by step for message notification integration for linphone ios
Thanks
